# TypeScript: excuting a function which returns middleware for express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I Have created an middleware which will validate the incoming data. the problem here is i created a function which take joi object as parameter and returns the middleware. which causes the below error. Also the error only happens during build and shows red swiggly line on vscode. Everything works fine during development.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>[]): Router', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
        Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Request': cache, credentials, destination, integrity, and 15 more.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>[]): Router', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2769)
View Problem (Alt+F8)
```

i think the problem here is the type of the function is different then the middleware function.

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { userRegister, userLogin, getUser } from '@controllers/users.controller';
import Route from '@interfaces/routes.interface';
import authenticate from '@middlewares/authenticate.middelware';
import validate from '@middlewares/validation.middleware';
import { loginSchema, signUpSchema } from '../joi/users.joi';
class UsersRoute implements Route {
  public path = '/auth';
  public router = Router();

  constructor() {
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }

  private initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.post(`${this.path}/signup`, validate(signUpSchema), userRegister);
    this.router.post(`${this.path}/login`, validate(loginSchema), userLogin);
    this.router.get(`${this.path}`, authenticate, validate(), getUser);
  }
}

export default UsersRoute;
```

and the validate

```
import HttpException from '@exceptions/HttpException';
import { NextFunction } from 'express';
import joi, { ObjectSchema } from 'joi';

const Validate = (schema: ObjectSchema = joi.object({})): ((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void) => {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const result = schema.validate(req.body);
    if (result.error) {
      next(new HttpException(406, result.error.message.split(`\"`).join('')));
    }
    next();
  };
};

export default Validate;
```

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, so I'm leaving just a comment: you should use 400 HTTP status code when your validation failed. 406 is used when for example a client asks you to get the data in the selected format (e.g. `application/json` in `Accept` header) but your server is not able to do so. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406

Comment: Can you show where `validate` (lowercase) is defined/imported/required in `initializeRoutes`?  Your validator returns a factory-type method but it's almost like you are passing your schemas into the returned function from Validate.

Comment: Also check if a proper `Request` and `Response` types are imported in the file where `Validate` is defined, that might be the issue because there might be a global type with the same name.

Comment: @Joe i have updated the code for the middleware functions.

Comment: @arkus u are right i didnt imported the Request and Response. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a silly mistake of not importing Request and Response from  express. if not imported it uses Request and Response from fetch api.

```
import HttpException from '@exceptions/HttpException';
import joi, { ObjectSchema } from 'joi';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'; //should be imported

const Validate = (schema: ObjectSchema = joi.object({})): ((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void) => {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const result = schema.validate(req.body);
    if (result.error) {
      next(new HttpException(406, result.error.message.split(`\"`).join('')));
    }
    next();
  };
};

export default Validate;
```